# How to use a IntVar to call an element in a 2d array

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a game that generates frames with questions in them with the answers as buttons below them. I am nearly finished the base code, but I need a way to compare the answer the player clicks on and the correct answer. To do this, I put the right answer in the first element of the element that corresponds to the question asked. ie [[correct answer, wrong, wrong, wrong], [correct, wrong, wrong, wrong]].

I am having trouble using a IntVar to call the right set of answers and access the right element.

```
def check_answer(self, answer, page_name):
    global answers
    score = IntVar(self)
    correct = IntVar(self)
    if answer == answers[correct][0]:
        s = score.get() + 1
        score.set(s)
    print(score)
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
    correct = correct.get()+1
    correct.set(correct)
```

When I press a button, I get this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Paul's stuff/Paul/CpmpProject/gamescreenv3.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    answer = tkinter.Button(self, text=answers[0][i], command=lambda answer=i: controller.check_answer(answer, "QuestionTwo"))
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Paul's stuff/Paul/CpmpProject/gamescreenv3.py", line 44, in check_answer
    if answer == answers[correct][0]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not IntVar
```

Comment: Please show me the code where you set the values of score and correct so i can try explain and solve your problem

Comment: I didn't know that I had to do that. I did some research and thought the default value for IntVar was 0 and so I didn't assign a value for score and correct as the index I needed was 0 at the start. The code above is the only code that refers to score and correct as it is part of a superclass that the questions inherit from.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the trouble you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I created a mini UI which will take user answer check against correct answer and if answer is correct it will add to score and display a pop up saying it was correct. Test it out and see if this is what you were looking for.

Copy and paste this into python and test it out:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()

        self.answers=['a','b','c','d']
        self.score = 0

        q1 = Label(self, text ="What is the answer?")
        q1.grid(row=0, column = 0)

        a1 = Button(self, text = self.answers[0], command = lambda: self.checkAnswer(self.answers[0]))
        a1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        a2 = Button(self, text = self.answers[1], command = lambda: self.checkAnswer(self.answers[1]))
        a2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        a2 = Button(self, text = self.answers[2], command = lambda: self.checkAnswer(self.answers[2]))
        a2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        a2 = Button(self, text = self.answers[3], command = lambda: self.checkAnswer(self.answers[3]))
        a2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def checkAnswer(self, answer):
        if answer == self.answers[0]:
            self.score += 1
            self.correct()
        else:
            self.wrong()

    def correct(self):
        self.popup = tk.Tk()
        self.popup.wm_title("Correct!!!")
        
        label = tk.Label(self.popup,text=("Correct answer, your score is:",self.score))
        label.pack()
        self.popup.mainloop()

    def wrong(self):
        self.popup = tk.Tk()
        self.popup.wm_title("wrong")
        label = tk.Label(self.popup,text=("wrong answer"))
        label.pack()
        self.popup.mainloop()
        
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```